# ibm_db for nodejs: using TCP/IP works fine but using SSL reports SQL30081N A communication error "selectForConnectTimeout"

Tags: node.js, ssl, db2, ibm-cloud

In a Node app with ibm_db, I am trying to connect to Db2 Warehouse on Cloud using ssl connection string.

On CentOS 7.8, using SSL connection string as below works fine.

```
var connStr = "DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxx.bluemix.net;PORT=50001;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=XXXXXXXXX;PWD=XXXXXXXXXXX;Security=SSL"
```

However, on RHEL 7.2, using SSL connection string does not work, SQL30081N is reported. It is same source code working on CentOS 7.8.

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. 
Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  
Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  
Location where the error was detected: "XXX.XX.XXX.XXX".  
Communication function detecting the error: "selectForConnectTimeout".  
Protocol specific error code(s): "115", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001\n
```

As a test, changing SSL connection string to TCP/IP connection string as below, it works on RHEL 7.2.

```
var connStr = "DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxx.bluemix.net;UID=XXXXXXXXX;PWD=XXXXXXXXXXX;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP";
```

On each environment, installed the latest IBM ODBC and CLI Driver via `npm install ibm_db`.

I think the certificate file for ssl connection is bundled with the driver package and will be used for connections, so ssl configuration does not required manually.

Or, would I need to configure anything else for using SSL on RHEL 7.2 ?

Comment: The 115 code on Linux indicates a timeout on the connection. Check if any firewall is blocking the SSL port configured for the Db2-server instance.  Also, port 50000 is not usually the SSL/TLS port but is instead usually the unencrypted port. Double check .

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply. Db2-server instance is Db2 Warehouse on Cloud managed by IBM. So, firewall is set up properly.

Comment: The firewall may be on your RHEL 7.2 hostname, or along the route from it to the cloud. The SSL port must be open all the way on that path.

Comment: Thanks. 443 (https) port is open on RHEL 7.2. We can use wget and npm install to get some files from outside.

Comment: Verify that the Db2-SSL port is open on RHEL (this is the port that IBM tells you to use for TLS/SSL with Db2, for example 50001 ). You also need to verify that the target Db2-instance is enabled for SSL (which is the default for all new Db2-instances).

Comment: I have question. Client side, our RHEL 7.2 need open 50001 too ? Server side is DaaS managed by IBM and SSL enabled.

Comment: Yes: if that is the _correct_ port that your Db2-server instance uses for SSL communications, then this port must be open all the way from your RHEL hostname to the cloud instance. RHEL may have its own firewall active.

Comment: I got it, thanks. I' ll check firewalld port 50001 opend.

Comment: HI, I check firewalld status on RHEL. it is stopped. I wonder why TCPIP connection is fine and SSL connection is not. Firewalld is stopped, so 50000 & 50001 port are same condition.

Comment: On your RHEL run `telnet  $db2_cloud_hostname 50001` (install telnet if necessary).  If the result is `Connected to ...` and then a hang, it means the port 50001 is open ALL THE WAY between RHEL and Db2-warehouse-on-cloud.  For any other result, some firewall blocks that port en-route.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested using traceroute with TCPIP option instead of telnet. Traceroute has reached destination  $db2_cloud_hostname.                                                                        [root@hogehoge test]# traceroute -n -q 1 -T -p 50001 dashdb-xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxx.bluemix.net
traceroute to dashdb-xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxx.bluemix.net (XXX.XX.XXX.XXX), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  XXX.XX.XXX.XXX  0.218 ms

Comment: You may need to involve IBM then (via a support request), and collect TCP traces, as mentioned here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cli-application-fails-sql30081n-rc-115-selectforreceivetimeout-function